# Custom posts with certain html

Tags: html

I'm not sure how to explain this, take this site for example http://www.collective.townofsilenthill.com/ say I wanted to create a page similar using wordpress. Instead of using code every time have a form in the admin area that adds a site with ease. Also able to have sections.

Anyone know if that's possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible – but it's not trivial. You'll basically need the following three components:

- Custom Post Types
- Custom Fields
- A page listing the entries

I suggest you have a look at the various pages and tutorials that are available covering these three topics. [Here](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-custom-post-types-in-wordpress/) would be one "How to Create Custom Post Types in WordPress" at WPBeginner.com that could get you started.